# Entity Framework Eager Load Web API Routes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Visual Studio generated this great route for me, where I can load an entity:

```
// GET: api/Jobs/5
[ResponseType(typeof(Job))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetJob(int id)
{
    Job job = await db.Jobs.FindAsync(id);

    if (job == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(job);
}
```

Here's the `Job` model this is based on:

```
public class Job
{
    public Job()
    {
        this.Regions = new List<Region>();
        this.Files = new List<JobFile>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Region> Regions { get; set; }
    public JobTypes JobType { get; set; }
    public int UserIDCreatedBy { get; set; }
    public int? UserIDAssignedTo { get; set; }
    public List<JobFile> Files { get; set; }
    public bool IsLocked { get; set; } // Lock for modification access
}
```

Here's the `JobFile` class, which `Job`s have a list of:

```
public class JobFile
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public int Job_ID { get; set; }
}
```

and `Pdf`, a subclass of `JobFile`:

```
public class Pdf : JobFile
{
    public Pdf()
    {
        this.PdfPages = new List<PdfPage>();
    }

    public int Index { get; set; }

    public List<PdfPage> PdfPages { get; set; }
}
```

Now, when I hit that route, I'd like to eagerly load all the `Pdf`s for a `Job`. I'm struggling with how I write that query using Linq, especially given the subclassing going on here. I need to replace this line in the route:

```
Job job = await db.Jobs.FindAsync(id);
```

I have a start to it I think:

```
// Eager load all the properties
IQueryable<Pdf> jobPdfs = (IQueryable<Pdf>)db.JobFiles.Where(jobFile => jobFile.Job_ID == id && jobFile is Pdf);
```

This should get me all the `Pdf`s I think. But I also want to load the `PdfPages` of `Pdf`s. How do I modify this statement to include that? The thing to do seems to be to use a `.Include(pdf => pdf.PdfPages)`,

Comment: I thought we had this [settled](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/119699/7251)?

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the where clause of your query by removing the `jobFile is Pdf` condition. Just use `OfType<Pdf>` like this:

```
IQueryable<Pdf> jobPdfs = db.JobFiles
   .OfType<Pdf>()
   .Where(jobFile => jobFile.Job_ID == id);
```

To eager load the `PdfPages` collection of `Pdf` class then just add `.Include(pdf => pdf.PdfPages)` like the following code:

```
IQueryable<Pdf> jobPdfs = db.JobFiles
   .OfType<Pdf>()
   .Include(pdf => pdf.PdfPages)
   .Where(jobFile => jobFile.Job_ID == id);
```